# Get the item index which is on focus inside a stackpanel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I have added 10 images in a stackpanel horizontally which is inside a scrollviewer. When user swipe the page the scrollviewer stops at certain position, if the scroll stops at &th image i want to get the name of the image. How to get that?

```
      for (int i = 0; i <= 59; i++)
        {

  Uri uri = new  Uri("http://d1mu9ule1cy7bp.cloudfront.net/2012/media/catalogues/47/pages/p_" + i + "/thump.jpg");
            ImageSource img1 = new BitmapImage(uri);
            Image rect = new Image { RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform() };

            rect.Source = img1;

            stack.Children.Add(rect);

        }
```

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="scroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

        <StackPanel Name="stack" Width="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  >

    </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your images are all the same size, you could calculate this by looking at the `HorizontalOffset` of the ScrollViewer.